# случаться vs происходить vs статься

Tags: словоупотребление, лексикон

Hey I'm confused about the use of  случаться vs происходить, as well as бывать and статься. They appear high up on most of the frequency lists I've seen, I've read that случаться  describes a random happening, while бывать is more something that happens more habitually.  So I guess, if that's agreed to be the case, do происходить and статься differ along that line as well? Or generally, what is the relationship between these words?
Thanks

Comment: 'статься' is used only in combinations 'может статься'  и 'как статься?'//// Может статься = maybe///Как статься = who can know this for sure///Как статься? Возможно это и произойдет (и случится) когда-нибудь

Comment: @Elena Not really, there's a lot of other "stable idioms" using *статься* (see for examples the link in my comment at the answer below). But yes, they are just that - idoms, thus we never use *статься* where *случаться/происходить* are used (except maybe a few special cases like *"что с тобой произодет?"/"что с тобой станется?"* where they are quite close but still not identical).

Comment: "случаться" can't be used in present continuous tense. In that case, use have to use "происходить".

Answer (score 2):

**случиться** - to happen accidentally or unexpectedly, to occur

> *Случилось* так, что в назначенный день адвокат заболел.
>
> *Случилось* странное происшествие.

**произойти** - to take place due to reasons, having an explanation

> Из-за явного нарушения правил безопасности *произошёл* пожар.
>
> Как и прогнозировали, в этом месяце *произошло* извержение вулкана.

**статься** (bookish, archaic) - to end up with some situation (for unknown reason), to have some destiny in the end

> *Может статься* (= сложиться так), что мы больше не встретимся.
>
> -- А *что сталось* с тем поручиком?
> -- Лет через 10 примкнул к повстанцам в Греции и погиб.

Comment: Funny that in the 2nd verse end at "Цунами"  - http://rockk.ru/text.php?readmore=9181 - personally I hear "Помогу тебя. Статься - погибнешь." Maybe it is a personal quirk. So, "статься" has a shade of lesser probability, of little hope, like "быть может",